# Polygons inside polygons QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I am pretty new with QGIS and GIS in general.

The thing is I have 2 shapefiles, the first one with municipalities (2457 polygons) and the second one with hydrological regions (363 polygons). I need to know which municipalities are inside which hydrological region. The shp with the hydrological regions has a column with an `ID` (`HR1`, `HR2`, etc.).

How can I add that value to each municipality?

Comment: Do you mean graphically, as you are just going to view one layer on top of another or do you mean you need an output from a tool in the processing toolbox?

Comment: Is each municipality within only one hydrological regions?

Comment: Thank you both! I need an output with this information, and yes, each municipality is within only one hydrological region

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Vector general > Join Attributes by Location` tool in Processing Toolbox(`Ctrl+Alt+T`).

1. Set `Input layer` to municipality layer
2. Set `Join layer` to hydrological regions layer
3. Select `within` only
4. Select only `ID` field in `Multiple selection` window
5. Set `Join type` to `Take attributes of the first matching feature only (one-to-one)` and run the tool

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tool `join attributes by location` :
https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location

He is located in the tab `Vector` -> `Data Management Tool`

It allows you to choose 2 layers and the spatial relation to join attribute from one layer to the other (intersect, touches, within, etc...). You can also choose the column to join.

In the pictue `layer_A` will be your municipalities, `layer_B` your Hydrological Regions and the `Geometric predicate` is `within`. So every municipalities obtain the ID of the Hydrological Regions they are in.

[image: tool]